# Queue won't switch to a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a Queue in jQuery to bunch together a set of animations,

```
$('#twitter').queue('myQueue',function(next){$('#titleTile').animate({top: 160}, {duration: 300, queue: false, complete: next})....
```

This works fine, but when I change the selector from `$('#twitter')` to `$('#gallery')` it still applies the animation to the `$('#twitter')` element?

I have no idea why it is doing this. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Perhaps it's a deployment problem? Maybe the old script is being read from the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation is happening on `#titleTile`.  You are not animating `#twitter`, you are just attaching the queue to this element.  Changing `#twitter` has no real affect on what you have in the function you have passed to `queue`.